# How to select individual parts of alembic (abc) file in Blender

Tags: objects, select, alembic

Question:
How can we select individual parts "mesh" or parts thereof in an alembic file in Blender?
We've tried the "edit mode" ->P and then selecting by loose parts..  No luck.. nada.

Background:
we're busy working on some pretty complex geometry. For this, we imported an animation from C4D via alembic into Blender. So far so good, the animation works, but, now we would like to selected individual objects "within" the alembic file, in order to isolate parts and later use Geometry Nodes for some additional effects using only specific areas of geometry.

We had no problem trying opening an obj file, that was easy and we could see all the individual parts, but not in alembic..

Thanks a ton. Best regards

Comment: Alembic should work as a regular mesh, but probably the transition from c4D to Blender does not have some functions, have you tried with FBX? you could also make a simple animation in C4D and export as Alembic to Blender and see if that works if so, then is probably the scene file

Comment: Hi, yes, we made an animation in C4D and exported that to Blender via Alembic.. that's the issue, that we aren't able to "break down" the geometry afterwards in Blender. With FBX no problem breaking down the individual parts of this tree, but no animation..

Comment: Not sure how it's working right now, last time i used C4D (R20) FBX had the option to export animation, if you are making the animation with mograph, you need to bake the animation before. Make a basic animation and export usign alembic as a test, if that does not work, share that basic animation and probably someone have the answer